# ¿Por que flutter_native_splash no muestra la imagen?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy intentando agregar un Splash Screen a mi aplicación con la librería [flutter native splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash).

Estos son los pasos que sigo:

**0. Elimino los archivos relativo a la splash screen**

Por recomendación de los comentarios aquí abajo, borro los `launch_background.xml` y ejecuto un `flutter clean`

**1. Agrego la dependencia**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  ...
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.11
```

**2. Diseño el Splash Screen**

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#FFFFFF"
  image: assets/logo_mdp.png
  android: true
  ios: true
```

también intenté hacerlo creando un archivo `flutter_native_splash.yaml` copiándolo de la documentación y descomentando la línea de la imagen.

```
  # The image parameter allows you to specify an image used in the splash screen.  It must be a
  # png file and should be sized for 4x pixel density.
  image: assets/logo_mdp.png
```

**3. Creo el Splash Screen**

```
flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```

**4. Modifico el values-v31/styles.xml**
Ya que otros paquetes me piden que utilice `Theme.MaterialComponents` modifico el archivo que crea `styles.xml`

```
<!-- <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">  BORRADO -->
<style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
</style>
```

**Error**

Sin embargo, la splash screen que muestra no dibuja la imagen.

Cuando diseño el splash screen en el `flutter_native_splash.yaml` cambia el color de fondo al que le indico. Si lo diseño directamente en el `pubspect.yaml` muestra una pantalla en blanco, no importa cual color le indique. En ninguno de los dos casos muestra la imagen que marco.

Intenté dar un nombre de un archivo que no existiera al declarar el splash screen para ver si el problema era que no encontraba el archivo pero no devolvía ningún mensaje de error, pero si lo devuelve:

> The file "assets/no_existe.png" set as the parameter "image" was
> not found.

así que el error debe ser otro.
**launch_background.xml que me queda al final**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/background"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Actualización**
He notado que no siempre va mal. Algunas veces funciona otras no. Además, si lo ejecuto con mi emulador siempre funciona correctamente

Comment: ¿Has añadido los recursos al pubsepc? Por si acaso, te recuerdo que cualquier recurso se tiene que declarar bajo la etiqueta assets, del archivo pubsepc.

Comment: Si, los he añadido

Comment: ¿Has eliminado los archivos relativo a la splash screen de Android y de IOS? Para que el plugin funcione, los archivos originales deben de eliminarse, pues no lo sobreescribe. Es un problema bastante muy molesto.

Comment: No, no lei nada en la documentación acerca de eso. Cuales son esos archivos?

Comment: Busca en Internet. No me los sé de memoria.

Comment: Supongo que te referías a los dos launch_background.xml. Los borre y configurar el package de 0 y sigue sin dar resultado. Hice Flutter clean antes de volver a condifurarlo

Comment: No recuerdo si eran esos, sinceramente. ¿Has pensado en hacerlo manualmente? Puedes modificar tanto el splashscreen como el launcher icon de forma nativa, directamente, desde la carpeta de Android o desde xcode con IOS. Podría ser una buena solución si todo lo demás falla.

Comment: Si, ahora mismo lo tengo hecho de forma nativa. Pero necesito que se mantenga hasta que haga ciertas comprobaciones una vez inicializada ya la app y había visto que la forma más sencilla era con este package

Comment: No sé si te he entendido... Tú muestras la splash screen nativa y luego cuando flutter carga su primer widget, todavía necesitas que se muestre la splash screen? En dicho caso, lo que puedes hacer es que la splash screen nativa, muestre solo un color de fondo y que el primer widget que cargue flutter sea una splash screen, el mismo color de fondo y la imagen que quieras. Y ya ahí, haces la lógica que necesites y actualizas la pantalla cuando tú lógica de haya completado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me fue imposible hacer que el package funcionase correctamente. Finalmente acabe por implementarlo de manera nativa con la siguiente clase:

```
class SplashScreenService{
    static late WidgetsBinding _widgetsBinding;
    /// Splash screen is being diisplayed
    static bool _splashScreenIsOn = true;
    
    /// Maintains the splash screen until the method remove() is called
    static void preserve(WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding){
        _widgetsBinding = widgetsBinding;   
        _widgetsBinding.deferFirstFrame();
    }

    /// Removes splashScreen. It only works if the splashScreen is being displayed 
    static void remove(){
      if(_splashScreenIsOn){
        _widgetsBinding.allowFirstFrame();
        _splashScreenIsOn = false;
      }
    }
}
```

Antes de implementarlo, hay que cambiar el splash screen nativo en el documento  `launch_background.xml`

**Aclaración:**
Esta implementación solo sirve para android. Cuando agregue la implementación para IOS actualizaré la respuesta